# Идентификация пользователя внутри приложения (iOS, Android) и покупки

Tags: android, ios, мобильные-приложения

Коллеги.
Нужна ваша консультация по следующему вопросу:

Необходимо реализовать мобильное приложение под iOS и Android в котором будет две возможности, которые вызывают вопросы.

1. Регистрация и идентификация пользователя
2. Внутренняя подписка.

Можете подсказать где и что почитать или какие-либо примеры реализации?

Вопрос вызывает следующее. Как четко идентифицировать пользователя приложением? Ну, скажем, человек скачал приложение через AppStore. Зашел в приложение. Если он ранее уже скачивал приложение (например с этого же аккаунта, но на iPad) и купил подписку, то разделы, которые он оплатил, должны быть автоматически доступны пользователю.

Следовательно по какому id можно этого пользователя идентифицировать? Можно ли каким-то образом получать appl id или google id?
Нашел информацию, что можно использовать UUID, но он же привязан к девайсу, а не к аккаунту. Значит, если пользователь оплатил подписку с iPhone, а запустил приложение на iPad - подписки не будет?
Нужно ли реализовывать для этого внутреннюю регистрацию в приложении? Или все же можно как-то идентифицировать пользователя?

Ну и где подробнее можно почитать про оплату? Может есть какие-то примеры. Как я понимаю это происходит через сами сервисы google и apple, но каких-то конкретных примеров не обнаружил....

Буду крайне признателен за советы по этим двум вопросам.

Answer (score 1):

Оба сервиса (и Google Play, и App Store) позволяют привязать несколько устройств к одному аккаунту. Таким образом, при совершении покупки, например, с телефона, для планшета сервис вернет, что покупка данной позиции уже совершалась.

Что касается разработки под Android, то можно ознакомиться с [этим уроком](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю можно обратиться к сервису Firebase https://console.firebase.google.com
Можно управлять аутентификацией и пользователями, вести аналитику, отправлять уведомления, удаленно менять настройки и пр. есть примеры под андроид и ios. Сам сейчас его изучаю.

Answer (score 0):

Для iOS существует механизм In-App Puchases https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/ - в нем реализованы покупки/оплаты в привязке к Apple ID независимот от устройства

Для Google - ссылку уже привели (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446654/271246)

Если нужно, чтоб покупки шарились между iOS и Android - то с этим посложнее, описано тут, например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200085/in-app-purchases-share-user-in-app-purchases-between-android-and-ios